# Part this place = leave this place?

Tags: grammar, meaning

19. Obs. to leave.

I saw this definition. It says it's obsolete, but it says we can use part to mean leave, so can we say the following sentences?

> We must part this place, we must leave this place.
>
> We must part this place, by that, I mean leave this place.

Just wondering, because I wasn't sure, because I couldn't find many examples using this construction or phrase on Google.

> [T]he result grand pieces that remain in the country are in the is
> that pieces of capital importance only remain in possession of men who
> happily are not likely to part this country by chance.

https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Magazine_of_Art/teBU24i6vnoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to+part+this+country%22&pg=PA319&printsec=frontcover

Comment: In your edit, you have copied and pasted text from the original incorrectly. Instead of grabbing text from a single column, you have grabbed text from both columns, and the result is incoherent.

Comment: If you look at the Google Books link, you will see that the words _part_  and _this country_ are in different columns of text. It's a weakness of Google Books that it 'reads' each line straight across the page, ignoring any division into columns and producing nonsense.

Comment: However, it looks like the text you are interested in uses the phrasal verb **part with**. It follows a different set of rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't speak of *parting a place.*

You *part from* another person, or two people *part* when they leave one another's company. This is standard, current English but, as your dictionary says, the sense
*to leave* is obsolete.

Comment: Can you use it in a poem that uses archaic language?

Comment: If you don't mind the risk that your readers won't understand you!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I wasn't sure "part this place" was correct since it's rarely used.

Comment: I didn't say it was correct. If your dictionary says that _leave_ is an obsolete meaning of _part_,, you can use it if you want, but only people familiar with archaic English will understand it!

Comment: Well, it did say that, but there was only 1 dictionary that said it. It's the one on thefreedictionary.com

Comment: Actually, the Free Dictionary gives definitions from several dictionaries (the title is in small print at the bottom of each set). The one you quote is from Webster's College Dictionary - there's also **30. (intr) archaic - to depart** from Collins English Dictionary.